# JavaScript/jQuery short hand function definitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, notation

I'm using a jQuery plugin that has its functions defined as such:

```
    $('#mydiv').pluginAction({
        someproperty: val, 
        format: 'mm hh',
        labels: ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'], 
        labels1: ['never', 'always']
    });
```

In my HTML page, I have multiple DIVs that have the same properties for `format`, `labels`, `labels1`, but different values for `someproperty`. Is there some type of JavaScript notation I can take advantage of to shorten the definition so that I don't have to have duplicate code?

Comment: Some plugins allow you to send an object literal to replace the defaults for the plugin. You could use this for you values that dont change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of dealing with this:

1. Create a function which fills in the blanks; or
2. If the plugin is yours, default those values to what you want.

Example of (1):

```
function props(val) {
  return {
    someproperty: val,
    format: 'mm hh',
    labels: ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'], 
    labels1: ['never', 'always']
  };
}

$("#mydiv").pluginAction(props("..."));
```

Answer (score 4):

Cletus has a very good answer, which allows you to produce very readable code. This is probably the best solution in your case.

Just for the record, something like the following would also be possible. You could create an object literal storing all fixed properties, and then just specify add extra properties (such as `someProperty` in your example) when needed by using [`jQuery#extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

```
var props = {
 format: 'mm hh',
 labels: ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'], 
 labels1: ['never', 'always']
};

$('#mydiv').pluginAction($.extend(props, { someProperty: val }));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with duplicating that sort of code. It actually makes it clear what sort of behavior applies on that given div. If however you're talking of hundreds of duplications, use what other people have suggested.